# What happens when I use Drawmij's Instant Summons on Dimensional Shackles?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, teleportation

If I place an enemy or individual in a set of dimensional shackles (I've already placed instant summons on the shackles), and I summon the shackles to me, what happens?

As I read the description of the spell and the shackles, I notice a few things:

- The individual can't teleport away from the shackles.
- The individual must go where the shackles go.
- The shackles must answer the summon because they are in my use, not in the use of some other individual.

So, would this combo:

- Create some sort of hiccup in time/space?
- Rip the shackled individual's limbs from its body?
- Teleport the individual to my location?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. I edited the question a bit to clean some things and hopefully improve the formatting. If you don't like any of the changes feel free to rollback the whole thing or [edit] again. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Rather than submitting possible outcomes , you may be better served by just asking what happens.

Comment: Related on [What items are considered worn or carried?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120716/what-items-are-considered-worn-or-carried) and [Are you considered to be wearing or carrying a restraining net/rope?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114702/are-you-considered-to-be-wearing-carrying-a-restraining-net-rope-etc-for-the-pu)

Answer (score 18):

## The outcome is ambiguous, ask your GM

*Drawmij's instant summons* specifies:

> If another creature is holding or carrying the item, crushing the sapphire doesn't transport the item to you, but instead you learn who the creature possessing the object is and roughly where that creature is located at that moment.

You'll have to ask your GM if the shackles binding a creature count as "holding or carrying". **If they do the shackles won't teleport** based on the clause.

**If your GM decides that being bound by shackles is not the same as holding or carrying then the shackles will teleport, unbinding the creature.** Nothing about *Drawmij's instant summons* would bring the creature bound by the item along with it, and *dimensional shackles* don't prevent *the shackles themselves* from teleportation.

Comment: I would have to disagree on that. If the shackles are still closed around the individual, they haven't been released from their purpose of holding said individual.  Only if the shackles are unlocked would they be allowed to free themselves from the individual.

Comment: @JoshWa5h that may be the concept of the shackles, but that's not how the rules work as written

Answer (score 4):

It says holding **or** carrying.  Someone bound in shackles is still carrying the shackles.

> Drawmij's Instant Summons
>
> "If another creature is holding or carrying the item, crushing the sapphire doesn't transport the item to you, but instead you learn who the creature possessing the object is and roughly where that creature is located at that moment."

The definitions of carrying are:

> "to wear or have on one's person"

> "to bear upon or within one"

> "To move while supporting"

Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carrying

If the individual wasn't wearing the shackles, they wouldn't work.  So **the individual is definitely carrying the shackles.**

Comment: Hello, welcome to RPG.SE. This is a good start of an answer, but answers should also stand on their own. A sentence or two indicating why carrying the shackles is important (perhaps quoting the relevant part of the spell) would make this a very good answer.

Comment: @BBeast, I updated my answer.  Does it now fit with what is expected of a good answer?  If it is still missing something, please let me know.