# Does the boiling mud stay on my character when I teleport?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation, environmental-hazards

My character fell into boiling mud and I used [*misty step*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step) to get out. When I teleport am I still covered in boiling mud, and will I continue to take damage?

Comment: What is the source of the boiling mud?

Comment: Hi Steve, welcome to the site. Take the [tour](/tour) to get your first badge. This is a fairly good first question, but if your DM is running a published adventure, it may help to tell us which one. The more details you can give us, the more specific answer we can give you.

Comment: Lake of mud in White Plume Mountain. So a sea of non-magical hot mud.

Comment: Related on [Misty Stepping from the Iron Bands of Billaro](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105577/misty-stepping-from-the-iron-bands-of-billaro)

Comment: Is it the "boiling lake" at the north of the dungeon map?

Comment: ...Or is it the room with the suspended platforms ("geysers and chains") at the east side of the map?

Comment: Suspended platforms

Comment: Related question for what follows when you Misty Step https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120716/what-items-are-considered-worn-or-carried

Answer (score 19):

According to the description from *Tales of the Yawning Portal* p. 100 (or [here on DNDBeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/adventures/tftyp/a4/white-plume-mountain#15BoilingLake)):

> Any creature that falls into the boiling mud takes 44 (8d10) fire damage at the start of each of its turns for as long as it remains in the mud.

The adventure book does not describe any mechanic for sustained damage once the creature exits the boiling mud. Of course, your DM is free to houserule otherwise, but if he doesn't it can be assumed that the mud does not continue sticking to you in an amount enough to cause further damage once you're out (no matter how you get out).

Now to address your direct question: **there is no mechanic for what happens to things stuck to you when you cast *misty step*.** Personally, I would rule that there would be a thin layer/traces of mud stuck to you afterwards (the same way that teleporting out of water might leave you wet), but not enough to do any significant damage.

Comment: Is there a difference between being "in the mud" and having "some mud on you"? I'd say yes and agree with your assessment.

Comment: The DM ruled it as boiling mud stuck on my person. I had to remove all my clothes while clinging to a rock and I lost all my items, including Blackrazor, which fell back into the boiling sea of mud. Had to run the rest of the dungeon completely naked.

Comment: @SteveJamesBradburyMagee: The DM is the ultimate arbiter of the rules... Though that seems like a questionable and very unfun ruling.

Comment: @V2Blast Unless the character is a natural exhibitionist.

Comment: @SteveJamesBradburyMagee Well, if you are fine with that, you are fine. But 5e goes lengths to prevent losing items (especially **magic** items), so I have to ask: is your DM familiar and experienced with 5e?

Answer (score 4):

## No

The spell only teleports "you." In common D&D interpretation that means you and your currently worn/equipped items.

According to the DMG p246

> For the purpose of these rules, an object is a discrete, inanimate item like a window, door, sword, book, table, chair, or stone, not a building or a vehicle that is composed of many other objects.

This would not include liquids of any form, and so they cannot be teleported (without being in a container).

Comment: I think the question is whether or not boiling mud would be considered a worn item (after all, you are wearing the mud.)

Comment: @NautArch I would say it doesn't count, but in the off case that someone would I've added another rule which discounts liquids altogether.

Comment: Not wearing the mud by choice :)

Comment: Teleportation as the ultimate bath?

Comment: It also telaports what you are carrying,  being covered in mud means technically you are carrying the mud...

Comment: @GarretGang I don't think it does - It's a liquid, just because it is touching you does not mean you are carrying it (unless you are arguing all of the liquid from the mudpit would follow, or the whole ocean if teleporting out of the sea.